# How to pass props to JSX string

Tags: jsx

If I use JSX string like:

```
const c = <div>{props.name}</div>
```

Then I want to render it like:

```
const app = () => <div>{c}</div>
```

How can I pass that name `attr` in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this ?

```
export default ({ name }) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;  //this will be saved in a Hello.js
```

then

```
const App = () => <div><Hello name="user"/></div> //Hello component imports here.
```

checkout the working demo below:

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rjzr5p)

or if you explain a bit more that would be better